# proxy.conf.json is not working in angular 6 when i use ng build

Tags: spring, angular

I am trying to create a project using proxy to connect to the backend, but when generating the project with ng build, the proxy configuration does not work as it does with ng serve.
To generate use the following command:

> ng build --prod --base-href = / myproyect /

Next I pass the files that I have of configuration:
proxy.conf.json:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/cystock/",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug"
    }
  }
```

global.ts:

```
export const GLOBAL = {
  production: true,
  url: 'api'//<-- 'API/' prefix needed for proxy configuration 
};
```

Note: The idea is to be able to consume localhost services, which is developed with JAVA using Spring as framework

Comment: The `proxy` configuration is intended to proxy calls when running the dev server via `ng serve`. After you run `ng build` you are responsible for the web server and its configurations

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that I do not know how to search to run the configuration, so it works

Answer (score 0):

As @vikas said, the proxy-config is strictly for development. It makes it easy to "mock" your endpoints while you're developing your application without the need for multiple configuration files.

The idea with proxy-config is that you proxy your production URL to a dev server (remote or local), and when you build your code without the proxy, it points to your production server.

To solve your issue specifically, just change `/api` to your production endpoint, and map it to a development server.